# Is it possible to send a message to a topic on one Sonic broker and have it replicated to a Queue on another Sonic broker?

Tags: sonicmq

I am using SonicMQ (version 7.6).
I have a Topic set up in production and code that publishes messages to that Topic.
I want to replicate these messages to a Queue running in a Sonic broker in another site.
Is it possible to configure SonicMQ to do this Topic-to-Queue replication, across brokers and sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no SonicMQ standard feature for doing this, as SonicMQ is mostly a standard JMS provider, so it has no built-in standard feature for manipulation or moving messages. SonicESB would be the "Sonic product" to solve such kind of problems.